# excel vba: set a table cell to read only

Tags: excel, vba

Is it possible to set a specific cell in a table to 'Read-Only'?
Or, set a column in the table to 'Read-Only'?
This is the idea of what I am trying to do:

```
Sub TableInsertRow()
    Dim oLo As ListObject
    Dim oNewRow As ListRow

    Set oLo = ActiveSheet.ListObjects("Table1")

    oLo.TableStyle = "tablestylelight3"
   'insert below

    Set oNewRow = oLo.ListRows.Add(AlwaysInsert:=True)

    oNewRow.Range.Cells(1, 1).Value = "Value For New cell"
    oNewRow.Range.Cells(1, 5).ReadOnly = True
    oNewRow.Range.Cells(1, 6).ReadOnly = True
    oNewRow.Range.Cells(1, 7).ReadOnly = True

End Sub
```

The last 3 lines are clearly not proper syntax, rather the idea I am trying to accomplish.
Or, if the table's columns can be set to read only, that will work as well.

Rich

Comment: You `lock` the cells then protect the sheet. see here: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff836172.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396

Comment: All of the cells in a worksheet are 'locked' by default. All that remains to actually lock them is to protect the worksheet. If you do not want some cells locked then unlock them prior to protecting the worksheet. Select cell(s), [ctrl]+1, Protection.

Comment: I know that you can do as you described for the sheet, but I only want those specific cells in the table only, and since the table will be growing as the VBA adds rows, I was hoping only to do those specific cells in the table.
Is it possible to make the cells 'Inactive' instead of read-only? Then they would be 'Greyed-Out' and not enterable?

Comment: Then you would unlock all the cells, lock each one as it gets added and protect the sheet.

Comment: @rtemen hey! Have you tried the solution below?

Answer (score 1):

You can use this basic script to make some cells range *ReadOnly*:

```
Private Sub Worksheet_SelectionChange(ByVal Target As Range)
If Not Intersect(ActiveCell, Range("A2:B4")) Is Nothing Then 'We make A2:B4 range readonly
Range("A1").Select 'when user selects some cell from the range above
MsgBox ("These cells are Readonly,So you can not Change") 'He will receive this massage
End If
End Sub
```

Just open VB editor (<kbd>ALT + F11</kbd>) choose sheet you want to make a read only cells on - double-click, paste this code.

Taken long time ago from [here](https://pallavikelkar.wordpress.com/2009/07/30/making-cells-readonly-in-excel-using-vba/)

Comment: Tank you, very easy and useful